# Python 3.11 installation: some modules are missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sqlite, ubuntu

I'll try to be as clear and specific as possible because I've seen so many people with the same problem, but none of the answers they had worked for me.

**The problem in question is**: missing modules when trying to import other modules, that (by far as I understand) are installed by default in Python 3.11. **eg: missing _sqlite3 when importing sqlite3.**

```
Python 3.11.0 (main, Jan 12 2023, 03:19:52) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user_name/opt/Python-3.11.0/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/__init__.py", 
  line 57, in <module> from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/user_name/opt/Python-3.11.0/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", 
  line 27, in <module> from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

**Context**

I'm currently working on a Dreamhost VPS, running on Ubuntu 20.04.5. Since it's a Dreamhost VPS keep in mind I can't uso **sudo**.

I've Python 3.8 installed globally, but I'm trying to set Python 3.11 with venv. The steps to install Python 3.11 were, as indicated by '[Installing a custom version of Python 3 by Dreamhost](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000702772-Installing-a-custom-version-of-Python-3)':

1. cd /home/user_name/opt
2. wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/Python-3.11.0.tgz
3. tar zxvf Python-3.11.0.tgz
4. cd Python-3.11.0
5. ./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/Python-3.11.0
6. make
7. make install

When running the **make** command I saw the following message:

```
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel
_lzma                 _tkinter              _uuid
readline
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


The following modules found by detect_modules() in setup.py have not
been built, they are *disabled* by configure:
_sqlite3
```

This is my **detect_modules()** in **setup.py**:

```
def detect_modules(self):
        # remove dummy extension
        self.extensions = []

        # Some C extensions are built by entries in Modules/Setup.bootstrap.
        # These are extensions are required to bootstrap the interpreter or
        # build process.
        self.detect_simple_extensions()
        self.detect_test_extensions()
        self.detect_readline_curses()
        self.detect_crypt()
        self.detect_openssl_hashlib()
        self.detect_hash_builtins()
        self.detect_dbm_gdbm()
        self.detect_sqlite()
        self.detect_platform_specific_exts()
        self.detect_nis()
        self.detect_compress_exts()
        self.detect_expat_elementtree()
        self.detect_multibytecodecs()
        self.detect_decimal()
        self.detect_ctypes()
        self.detect_multiprocessing()
        self.detect_tkinter()
        self.detect_uuid()

        # Uncomment the next line if you want to play with xxmodule.c
#        self.add(Extension('xx', ['xxmodule.c']))

        self.addext(Extension('xxlimited', ['xxlimited.c']))
        self.addext(Extension('xxlimited_35', ['xxlimited_35.c']))
```

So after running the commands I just mentioned, I proceeded to setup the virtualenv to test Python 3.11:

1. cd /home/user_name/opt
2. /home/user_name/opt/Python-3.11.0/bin/python3 -m venv venv
3. source venv/bin/activate

And then I got the **ModuleNotFoundError** I mentioned at the start of the question.

**Things I tried/saw:**

When I checked my Python 3.11 directory, I saw that in **/home/user_name/opt/Python-3.11.0/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload** the cpython files for the modules I don't have are just not there, **e.g**: */home/user_name/opt/Python-3.11.0/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so** where as in my Python 3.8, they're indeed there: **/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so**

I tried copying the cpython file from my 3.8 to my 3.11 and renaming it:

1. cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /home/user_name/opt/Python-3.11.0/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload
2. mv /home/user_name/opt/Python-3.11.0/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /home/user_name/opt/Python-3.11.0/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

Then when I ran Python 3.11 I got the following error:

```
Python 3.11.0 (main, Jan 12 2023, 04:33:33) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _sqlite3 # this works just fine
>>> import sqlite3 # throws error
356306 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python
```

Tried recompiling Python and running **./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/Python-3.11.0 --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions** and didn't work.

Hope I was clear enough and thanks in advance.

Comment: try installing development libraries for sqlite3, `sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev`

Comment: I can't use sudo as I mentioned since it's a Dreamhost VPS. @GauravPathak

Comment: I installed https://www.sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-autoconf-3420000.tar.gz from source but that did not help. Any idea what the right url should be?

Comment: I remember using that exact same URL and it didn't work anyways. Don't know about any other urls apart from the sqlite org page.

Comment: After manual installation of  the sqlite libs and header files pass the locations of those files to the compiler (-I flag)and the linker (-L flag). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149359/what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-add-cflags-and-ldflags-to-configure

Comment: have you run `./python -m test` after the installation?

Comment: Pl see my edited answer

Comment: @Ignacio Frizzera, I added a bounty since I have a similar problem. When running make, can you check if you also get an error message (*** WARNING: renaming "_sqlite3" since importing it failed: /path/to/build/Python-3.11.7/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.11/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_deserialize

Comment: Hey @Raphael, I commented some of the answers because I saw you put a bounty on the question, but sadly we migrated our servers to AWS EC2 instances a couple months after I had this trouble, so there's no way I can replicate the error I mentioned. I don't know if I should close the question or just let it be here and see if someone comes with a solution to your problem

Comment: Let's leave it open for now, hoepfully somebody has an answer...

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.sqlite.org/download.html, download the source code for the latest version (e.g., sqlite-autoconf-*.tar.gz)

Then in the expanded directory :

```
./configure --prefix=/tmp/sqlite3 && make -j4 install
```

Now in Python source directory :

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/tmp/sqlite3/lib/pkgconfig
./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/Python-3.11.0 --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make -j4
```

sqlite3 module should be working in the newly built Python

Comment: that kinda works, but I have the issue that I get an error message when I compile python (see comment above as well): *** WARNING: renaming "_sqlite3" since importing it failed: /path/to/build/Python-3.11.7/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.11/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_deserialize. Any idea what could be the cause for that

Comment: @Raphael You may be missing other packages as well, see https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2625

Comment: Since the warning I get is off topic, I opened a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77901277/building-python-from-source-sqlite3-built-but-not-imported